# Merge MYSQL & Postgresql

Tags: mysql, database, merge

How can I merge two different database MySQL & PostgreSQL. how can I import PostgreSQL data to mysql database. is there any other way for the same

Comment: Having ODBC driver for the Postgre database, you could use this Data Import tool - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html. It allows to insert, update and replace data in the target tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a database migration tools

Answer (score 3):

You can use a database migrator tool, as for example openDbCopy(open source)  or ESF data migrator tool (commercial).